# How can I use Dapper's strongly-typed query parameters with Sybase ASE?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sap-ase, dapper

[Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) can pass query parameters as anonymous objects, and supports any ADO.NET data provider. However, when running the following query against the Sybase 15 ADO.NET drivers:

```
using (var connection = new AseConnection("..."))
{
    connection.Open();

    var results = connection.Query<Foo>(
        "dbo.sp_columns", new { table_name = "dbo.sysusers"}, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

... the following error is thrown:

```
Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException: Procedure sp_columns expects parameter @table_name, which was not supplied.

at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ᜁ(Int32 A_0)
at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ᜄ()
at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ᜀ(CommandBehavior A_0)
at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryInternal>d__13`1.MoveNext() in SqlMapper.cs: line 579
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in SqlMapper.cs: line 536
```

Changing it to a Dapper `DynamicParameters` set with "@table_name" also doesn't work.

How can I pass strongly-typed parameters to Sybase with Dapper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the reason seems to be something to do with Sybase's `AseParameter` class, and not correctly mapping `DbType` to `AseDbType` values.

You can work around the problem by defining a custom Dapper `IDynamicParameters` set, and populating it with `AseParameter` objects directly:

```
public class AseCommandParameters : List<AseParameter>, SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters
{
    public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in this)
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

And then passing an instance into the query:

```
using (var connection = new AseConnection("..."))
{
    connection.Open();

    var parameters = new AseCommandParameters
    {
        new AseParameter("@table_name", "dbo.sysusers")
    };

    var results = connection.Query<Foo>("dbo.sp_columns", parameters, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

This works, and also lets you specify the `AseDbType` for each parameter.

Comment: That is very interesting! I can't think of a clean way to make this into the "core" library, but... Fascinating.

Comment: I removed the wiki here ... don't see the point, this is pretty much the reason for IDynamicParameters, nice usage I approve.

Comment: Also recommend you open up a ticket with sybase here ... they are the first provider I know that is **this** broken

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Strange that this problem was originally described at 2011, now is 2016 and it is still not fixed. Can you tell more detail where I can report this bug ?

Comment: It's 2018 and Sybase is even more broken and not even _slightly_ compatible with dotnet Core. We're replacing it with MSSQL, for no other reason than compatibility. I wonder who exactly they think their customers are.

Comment: There is a Sybase .NET Core connection package on Nuget (AdoNetCore.AseClient). It _wasn't_ written by Sybase!