# Entity Framework objects from SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datawindow

I've been working on a project which is based on PowerBuilder and DataWindow objects.
Now, one of the things we want is to "grab" the DataWindow objects and convert them to .NET objects (in C#) by basing them on the query. From that query I want EF to analyse it and build an object that mirrors the object retrieved by that query/datawindow. The data is pulled from 4 different tables on a Sybase ASE database.

I was under the impression that I could tell EF to behave like that by passing it the query and letting it build the object but I've been unable do to so and I've sort of hit a brick wall since DataWindow.NET (from Sybase) is a discontinued project (in 2008) and I really can't find any other alternative besides EF.

If the intended behavior is possible, could someone point me in the right direction?
And if not, is there any component/framework that behaves like intended?

Comment: Did you look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)? Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7823668/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold Did you intend to place the two links to be the same? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't work this way. You can't give it some SQL and have it hydrate some .NET objects for you. You can however do this using [Dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: Surely EF can materialize entities from raw SQL, but I agree with you that Dapper is a far better choice (hence my comment above).

Comment: No, I actually didn't know Dapper. I'll definitely take a look at it (once the wifi decides to stop acting up). Could any of you please elaborate on why EF doesn't behave like intended? Both of you mention that it can take SQL queries and materialize objects but I'm not following on the reasons that, if it can do that, why it won't just create the objects from that. Also, where does Dapper differ from PetaPoco (for example): http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/

Comment: @Zed_Blade I don't know all differences. I only know that Dapper would fit the bill. EF would behave as intended (i.e. create entity objects from raw SQL) but i's not its core functionality and it will give you a lot of overhead.

Comment: @GertArnold well, after looking at the performance benchmarks I think you're absolutely right. The application is intended to be a high-performance one (less than 2s between request and response on at least 90% of the requests) so this solution will be perfect. Thank you, both of you.