# Dapper 1.42 and Sybase.AdoNet45.AseClient doesn't insert string variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sybase, dapper

Moving off of Sybase is not an option and a requirement is to share session state between several .NET web applications. I've been tasked with creating a SessionStateStoreProvider that will work with Sybase.

We're using Sybase ASE 15.0, ASP.NET 4.61, it's an mvc web application. I've created a models library and a repository library for accessing the database. The repository library contains a base class for common methods, etc for accessing the database. Using Dapper 1.42, and Sybase.AdoNet45.AseClient.

This is the model class that represents the database table for session state fields. I've changed the table so all of the columns marked as varchar and varbinary will allow null data.

```
public class AspNetSession
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public DateTime LockDate { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public int LockId { get; set; }
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public int Flags { get; set; }
    public string SessionItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I need to write for doing a database operation. In this case I'm attempting an insert. The Insert command looks like it works and returns one data record has been added to the database, but when I examine the database the table has  one record inserted, but all of the string fields in the database are set to null.

```
public int Insert( AspNetSession session )
{
    const string sqlCmd = "insert into dbo.AspNetSessions " + 
                          "(SessionId, ApplicationName, Created, Expires, LockDate, Locked, LockId, Timeout, Flags, SessionItems ) " +
                          "Values(@SessionId, @ApplicationName, @Created, @Expires, @LockDate, @Locked, @LockId, @Timeout, @Flags, @SessionItems ) ";

    return Connection.Execute( sqlCmd, session );
}
```

I've also tried passing the parameters using the new {...}, with the same results.

```
return Connection.Execute( sqlCmd, new { session.SessionId,
                                         session.ApplicationName,
                                         session.Created,
                                         session.Expires,
                                         session.LockDate,
                                         session.Locked,
                                         session.LockId,
                                         session.Timeout,
                                         session.Flags,
                                         session.SessionItems } );
```

I've tried the following code (I also tried without the @ symbol in front of the name parameter). I get the exception

> Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException: Must declare variable '@SessionId'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var parameterList = new List<AseParameter>();
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@SessionId", session.SessionId ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@ApplicationName", session.ApplicationName ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@Created", session.Created ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@Expires", session.Expires ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@LockDate", session.LockDate ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@Locked", session.Locked ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@LockId", session.LockId ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@Timeout", session.Timeout ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@Flags", session.Flags ) );
parameterList.Add( new AseParameter( "@SessionItems", session.SessionItems ) );

return Connection.Execute( sqlCmd, parameterList );
```

Here's code from the base class that creates the connection.

```
public BaseRepository()
{
    ConnectionStringSettings css = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppName"];
    if (Connection == null)
        Connection = new AseConnection(css.ConnectionString);

    Connection.ConnectionString = css.ConnectionString;        
}
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose( true );
    GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
}
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if ( !_disposed)
    {
        if ( disposing )
            _connection.Dispose();

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
public IDbConnection Connection
{
    get { return _connection; }
    set { _connection = value; }
}
public string ProviderName
{
    get { return _providerName; }
    set { _providerName = value; }
}

private string _providerName = "Sybase.Data.AseClient";
private IDbConnection _connection;
private bool _disposed = false;
```

database schema

```
create table [AspNetSessions] 
    ([SessionId]       varchar(64) null,
     [ApplicationName] varchar(64) null,
     [Created]         datetime not null,
     [Expires]         datetime not null,
     [LockDate]        datetime not null,
     [Locked]          bit not null,
     [LockId]          int not null,
     [Timeout]         int not null,
     [Flags]           int not null,
     [SessionItems]    varchar(3800) null)
```

on [default]

Comment: Can you show the entire method where you are inserting the data?

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table.

Comment: When you say _all of the string fields in the database are set to null_ I assume that you only mean the `SessionId`, `ApplicationName`, and `SessionItems` columns and the others have the correct data.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, everything else is inserted properly. Just the 3 fields that are varchars are set to null.

Comment: The Insert method shown above is the original code that sets the strings to null, the other code bits are what I've tried that doesn't work. Do you want to see the other methods used for creating the connection?

Comment: I finally downloaded the Dapper source code and added the *.cs files to a newly created library project and included that into my solution. I also added the CommandParameter solution found at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823668/how-can-i-use-dappers-strongly-typed-query-parameters-with-sybase-ase. Once I got it working I removed the new project with the Dapper source files and installed the version from Nuget. After that, it didn't work again, so I removed the Dapper nuget package and added the library project I created with the dapper source files. It works again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried specific x86 and x64 builds with no luck.

I tried going back to VS2013, it didn't work with the Nuget library and it can't build the source code.

Nuget library version of Dapper: The added CommandParameter class doesn't get called for the parameters when adding parameters.

The way I got it to work was to download Dapper source from Nuget and added the source into a separate library, then included the library as a reference.

In a nutshell, Sybase and Dapper 1.42 only works in VS2015 and requires source to be included in the project.