# Passing Variables into Dapper are query parameters... "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection, dapper, sap-ase

Ok , I"m doing what looks like a simple Dapper query

but if I pass in my studId parameter, it blows up  with this low level networking exception:

{"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied."}

if I comment out the line of sql that uses it, fix the where clause, ,and comment out the line  where it's added the the parameters object. It retrieves rows as expected.

I've spent the last 2.5 days trying everything I could think of, changing the names to match common naming patterns, changing type to a string (just gave a error converting string to number), yadda yadda yadda..

I'm at a complete loss as to why it doesn't like that parameter, I look at other code that works and they pass Id's just fine...

At this point I figure it has to be an ID-10-t that's staring me in the face and I'm just assuming my way right past it with out seeing it.

Any help is appreciated

```
public List<StudDistLearnSchedRawResponse> GetStudDistanceLearningScheduleRaw( StudDistLearnSchedQueryParam inputs )
        {
            var aseSqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString( "SybaseDBDapper" );

            string mainSql = " SELECT " +
                             " enrollment.stud_id,  " +
                             " sched_start_dt,  " +
                             " sched_end_dt,   " +
                             " code.code_desc, " +
                             " student_schedule_dl.enrtype_id,     " +
                             " student_schedule_dl.stud_sched_dl_id,   " +
                             " dl_correspond_cd,  " +
                             " course.course_name,   " +
                             " stud_course_sched_dl.sched_hours,    " +
                             " actual_hours,  " +
                             " course_comments as staff_remarks,  " + // note this column rename - EWB
                             " stud_course_sched_dl.sched_item_id ,  " +
                             " stud_course_sched_dl.stud_course_sched_dl_id " +
                             "  from stud_course_sched_dl     " +
                             "     join student_schedule_dl on student_schedule_dl.stud_sched_dl_id           = stud_course_sched_dl.stud_sched_dl_id  " +
                             "     join course on stud_course_sched_dl.sched_item_id      = course.sched_item_id  " +
                             "     left join code on student_schedule_dl.dl_correspond_cd = code.code_id " +
                             "     join enrollment_type on student_schedule_dl.enrtype_id = enrollment_type.enrtype_id " +
                             "     join enrollment on enrollment_type.enr_id              = enrollment.enr_id " +

                             "   where enrollment.stud_id = @studId " +

                             "     and sched_start_dt >= @startOfWeek" +
                             "     and sched_end_dt <= @startOfNextWeek";


            DapperTools.DapperCustomMapping<StudDistLearnSchedRawResponse>();

            //string sql = query.ToString();

            DateTime? startOfWeek     = StartOfWeek( inputs.weekStartDateTime, DayOfWeek.Monday );
            DateTime? startOfNextWeek = StartOfWeek( inputs.weekStartDateTime.Value.AddDays( 7 ) , DayOfWeek.Monday );

            try
            {
                using ( IDbConnection db = new AseConnection( aseSqlConnectionString ) )
                {
                    db.Open();

                    var arguments = new
                    {
                        studId = inputs.StudId, //  it chokes and gives a low level networking error - EWB
                        startOfWeek = startOfWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                        startOfNextWeek  = startOfNextWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
                    };

                    List<StudDistLearnSchedRawResponse> list = new List<StudDistLearnSchedRawResponse>();

                    
                    list = db.Query<StudDistLearnSchedRawResponse>( mainSql, arguments ).ToList();
                    
                    return list;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Here is the input object

```
  public class StudDistLearnSchedQueryParam
    {
        public Int64 StudId;
        public DateTime? weekStartDateTime;
    }
```

Here is the dapper tools object which just abstracts some ugly code to look nicer.

```
namespace EricSandboxVue.Utilities
{

    public interface IDapperTools
    {
        string        ASEConnectionString { get; }
        AseConnection _aseconnection      { get; }
        void          ReportSqlError( ILogger DalLog, string sql, Exception errorFound );
        void          DapperCustomMapping< T >( );
    }

    public class DapperTools : IDapperTools
    {
        public readonly string _aseconnectionString;

        public string ASEConnectionString => _aseconnectionString;

        public AseConnection _aseconnection
        {
            get
            {
                return new AseConnection( _aseconnectionString );
            }
        }

        public DapperTools( )
        {
            _aseconnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "EIS_ASESQL_CONNECTIONSTRING" );

        }

        public void ReportSqlError( ILogger DalLog, string sql, Exception errorFound )
        {
            DalLog.LogError( "Error in Sql" );
            DalLog.LogError( errorFound.Message );

            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            DalLog.LogError( sql );

            //}

            throw errorFound;

        }

        public void DapperCustomMapping< T >( )
        {
            // custom mapping
            var map = new CustomPropertyTypeMap(
                                                typeof( T ),
                                                ( type, columnName ) => type.GetProperties( ).FirstOrDefault( prop => GetDescriptionFromAttribute( prop ) == columnName )
                                               );
            SqlMapper.SetTypeMap( typeof( T ), map );
        }

        private string GetDescriptionFromAttribute( System.Reflection.MemberInfo member )
        {
            if ( member == null ) return null;

            var attrib = (Dapper.ColumnAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute( member, typeof(Dapper.ColumnAttribute), false );

            return attrib == null ? null : attrib.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the SQL string building to this(below), but leave everything else the same(Including StudId in the args struct)... it doesn't crash and retrieves rows, so it's clearly about the substitution of @studId...

```
                         // "   where enrollment.stud_id = @studId " +
                         "     where sched_start_dt >= @startOfWeek" +
                         "     and sched_end_dt <= @startOfNextWeek";
```

Answer (score 1):

You name your data members wrong. I had no idea starting a variable name with @ was possible.

The problem is here:

```cs
var arguments = new
    {
        @studId = inputs.StudId, //  it chokes and gives a low level networking error - EWB
        @startOfWeek = startOfWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
        @startOfNextWeek  = startOfNextWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
    };
```

It should have been:

```cs
var arguments = new
    {
        studId = inputs.StudId, //  it chokes and gives a low level networking error - EWB
        startOfWeek = startOfWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
        startOfNextWeek  = startOfNextWeek.Value.ToShortDateString(),
    };
```

The @ is just a hint to Dapper, that it should replace with a corresponding member name.
@@ has special meaning in some SQL dialects, that's probably what makes the trouble.

Comment: I tried that already. I just retested it, I used the arguments exactly as you show, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Oddly, if i leave the @ off there I can get the exact same error(facing the issue on new sql call)

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823668/how-can-i-use-dappers-strongly-typed-query-parameters-with-sybase-ase ? It looks like something about Ase parameters is broken. It might be worth giving that solution a try.

Comment: I rewrote it not using dapper and it still reproduce, i hard code the parameter arg and it works, whether I pass it in or not... so clearly an parameter/args issue

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I Found out.

The Sybase implementation has a hard time with Arguments.

It especially has a hard time with arguments of type int64 (this existed way pre .NetCore)

So If you change the type of the passed in argument from int64 to int32, everything works fine.

You can cast it, or just change the type of the method parameter